# Fitting a curve to find argument of transfer function

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I have a pair of data vectors, `x` and `y`, defined as follows:

```
data = [
     0    0; 
     0.05 1.108646244630E-01;
     0.10 2.217423074817E-01;
     0.15 3.325947375398E-01;
     0.20 4.434863433851E-01;
     0.25 5.543595496420E-01;
     0.30 6.652338361973E-01;
     0.35 7.761094191116E-01;
     0.40 8.869865144820E-01;
     0.45 9.978653384221E-01;
     0.50 1.108746107036E+00];

 x = data(:,1);
 y = data(:,2);
```

they are related by the equation

```
y = (cos(k*L)^2-(0.8194*k*cos(k*L)*sin(k*L))*x;
```

where `k=3` is a fixed number.

Now I want to find the right value of `L` for which the above equation fits my data.

Although the data appears linear, I want to find the right value of `L` for which data fits the initial linear part of sinusoidal curve of this transfer function.

How do I solve this kind of problem?

Comment: This is an optimization/curve fitting problem. Do you have the curve fitting toolbox? Which MATLAB version are you using? Do you know approximately what the value of `L` should be? You can start by guessing a vector of values for `L` and evaluating the error, then improving the guess until you find a satisfactory value. Please try something yourself and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it using the [curve fitting toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting.html):

1. Start by defining `x` and `y`, then calling `cftool`:

   [image: Command window screenshot]
2. You will get the following screen, where you need to choose your "X data" and your "Y data":

   [image: cftool start screen screenshot]
3. After choosing the `x` and `y` vectors we created before, a default linear fit will be shown:

   [image: cftool default fit screenshot]

   (as you can already see, this is a practically an ideal fit for the relation between `x` and `y`)
4. To make `cftool` fit your desired model, click the dropdown box that says "Polynomial" and choose the option "Custom Equation", then write your model. If the *Auto fit* checkbox is selected (it is by default), you will get a fit right away:

   [image]

As you can see, we got that `L = 0.7157`, but we also see that the fit doesn't really go through the points, which means that at least one of the following statements is true:

- The model (i.e. the custom equation in which `L` appears) is incorrect.
- The fitting problem is set up incorrectly (e.g. the found `L` is outside of the expected bounds etc.).

It is up to you to find the root of the problem (could be misplaced parentheses in the model) and fix it.